# Is there a center of charge in a system in the same way as there is center of mass?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, approximations

When we establish relation between mass and charges, we take parameters such as

- The law governing the property (Coulomb's for charge, Newton's for mass)
- The potential associated with them (Gravitational versus electrical)
- Both being fundamental forces of nature

Similarly can we take center of charge just as we take a centre of mass in many approximations?